# How Does Wordpress Read Comment Title?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I'm working on my own little back end framework for future clients and I'm making a folder named "Forms" to store all of my forms for CMS interaction.  Inside the forms folder I'd like to store .php files similar to wordpress style plugins that I can title in the comments code like wp does... ie

```
/*
Plugin Name: Name Of The Plugin
Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 1.0
Author: Name Of The Plugin Author
Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
*/
```

I'm wondering how WP reads that data as it is commented out... do they use file_get_contents('plugin.php'); and parse it as well as include the plugin?  Is there a php function to actually read comments?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Read the file by FTP or file_Get_contents()`
2. [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) each line by `:` and get result in `array`
3. `array[0]` makes the key and `array[1]` makes the value.

Comment: Using file get contents strips out all php comments...I'm wondering how this would work?

Answer (score 3):

Wordpress has created its own function to handle file headers. I used this in my new Total Widget Control Plugin. Here's the function name and help docs on how to use it.

**get_file_data( $file_path, $headers, $context)**

- http://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header

string $file: Path to the file

array $default_headers: List of headers, in the format array('HeaderKey' => 'Header Name')

string $context: If specified adds filter hook "extra_{$context}_headers"

Comment: using get_file_data, how does one extract the header names from the file? The function seemes to return an empty array each time.